# Can I create a partition table on a bare drive with an existing filesystem?

Tags: partition, ext4, partition-table

I've inherited a machine with an `ext4` filesystem on a drive with **no partitions** (and nothing else fancy, no LVM, etc.).

Is it possible to create a partition table on this drive **and** preserve the existing ext4 fileystem? — i.e., somehow slightly shrink the partition, move the superblock, then create a partition table?

(Obviously resizing this could be risky, incur data loss, etc. — this is mostly an academic question.)

```
$ lsblk /dev/sdc
NAME MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sdc    8:32   0 54.6T  0 disk /data

$ tune2fs -l /dev/sdc
...
First block:              0
...

$ fdisk -l /dev/sdc
Disk /dev/sdc: 54.57 TiB, 60001666203648 bytes, 117190754304 sectors
Disk model: LOGICAL VOLUME
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 262144 bytes / 786432 bytes

$
```

Comment: This is possible with Btrfs because [Btrfs does not use the very beginning of itself](https://superuser.com/q/1208555/432690). One can create a DOS partition table in the MBR and define a partition starting at the sector 0. I have done this for fun, but I haven't tested with GPT. Your device is large, you need GPT. If you had space at the end for the secondary GPT then crafting an exotic GPT that defines the first partition from 0th sector, plus in-place converting to Btrfs may work, I guess.

Comment: [Here](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Layout) I found that ext4 leaves 1024 bytes for "x86 boot sectors and other oddities". A minimal GPT needs 3 logical sectors at the beginning of the device (protective MBR, primary header, 4 entries), but according to `gdisk` officially it should be "16KB or larger". It seems in general you could easily create a DOS partition table in MBR, but not a GPT. Do you want a partition table that defines one large partition with the existing filesystem? Or can it be any formally-well-looking partition table, but "fake"?

Answer (score 0):

This is very tricky and the good advice is back up the drive before you attempt anything like this. It would be much easier to do this by copying everything off the drive and then copying it back once you have partitioned it.

If you must attempt it this way then from a high level you need to:

1. Resize the existing filesystem with resize2fs. Shrinking the existing partition will create extra space at the **end** (not the beginning)
2. Move the entire file system to the right - away from the beginning of the drive. You need at least 17k for GPT partition table but perhapse 1mb is safer.  ddrescue can do this. Though **be very careful if the new location overlaps the old one**. You might accidentally trash your data.
3. Use a partitioning tool of your choice (eg: cfdisk) to create a partition exactly where you put your data in step 2. DO NOT format this partition!

Again this is not advisable, and I am deliberately not giving command by command instructions because I can't be sure you won't screw up your data.